# Getting Version of already loaded DLL (Windows API)

Tags: winapi, dll, version, loadlibrary

ok, getting the file version of a dll before loading, is easy. im using GetFileVersionInfoSize + GetFileVersionInfo + VerQueryValue and it works like a charm.

but what if the dll is already loaded? i know you can use LoadLibrary + IMAGE_DOS_HEADER + IMAGE_NT_HEADERS to retrieve certain information such as the function names etc. i noticed that IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER has different version fields such as MajorImageVersion & MinorImageVersion etc. i tried pretty much everything, but those fields are not always set and when they are, they dont match the values returned by GetFileVersionInfo. so im guessing im looking in the wrong place. any ideas?

Comment: `GetModuleFileName` will give you the filename. `LoadLibrary` first if you don't know the HMODULE of the loaded dll.

Comment: who said anything about the filename? im trying to get the fileversion of an already loaded dll.

Comment: Once you have the name you can use whatever `GetFileVersionInfoSize + GetFileVersionInfo + VerQueryValue` code you have already. Whether the .dll is already loaded or not is immaterial as far getting the version info.

Comment: yea, i just got what you were trying to say and was about to edit my comment. i already know the filename, so calling GetFileVersionInfo wouldnt be a problem. but thats not the solution im looking for. when loading a dll, all its informations are already stored in memory. im trying to figure out where to find the fileversion information in memory. but maybe im wrong, maybe you cant access that by simply using IMAGE_NT_HEADERS etc.

Comment: Once the .dll is loaded, it's already been mapped into the memory space of the process, and (some of it) read from disk already. Once you access the same file via `GetFileVersionInfo` it will hit the same memory cache, so there is little to no penalty for doing it the official way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once the DLL is loaded, you can do this:

1. use `GetModuleHandle()` to get a handle to the DLL.
2. use that handle with `FindResource()`/`LoadResource()`/`LockResource()` to access the DLL's `RT_VERSION` resource data.
3. *make a copy* of that resource data to a memory block you allocate  (important!). Use `SizeofResource()` to know how many bytes to allocate and copy.
4. pass that memory block to `VerQueryValue()` to access its `VS_FIXEDFILEINFO` structure, which contains the DLL's version numbers.

Step 3 is important because `VerQueryValue()` needs access to writable memory (it relies on various fixups made within the content of the memory).  The memory pointer returned by `LockResource()` is pointing at read-only memory.  If you attempt to use the resource pointer directly, `VerQueryValue()` will crash.

Comment: thanks for your help. that sounds like a decent approach.

im wondering however if there is even a "simpler" one, without the need for additional api calls.

looks like you can access the resource data by passing the IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_RESOURCE constant to the DataDirectory field in IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER. now im gonna play with it a bit and try to get it to work.

Comment: Using the technique I describe is easier and safer than drilling down into the PE header directly.  Navigating the PE is complex.

Comment: yea i know, but im trying to get a better understanding of the whole pe madness. its easy if you already know the answer, but i guess i just like challenging myself.

Comment: It sounds like you want to explore PE files. There are plenty of good articles on that. Feel free to read them. But please don't mix that up with the answer to the question that you asked. Which this is.

Comment: well, there is obviously nothing wrong with Remy Lebeau's approach. it works like a charm. but i just like having various options. it depends on the food wether you use a fork or a spoon. same goes for programing. the more you learn, the better choice you will make in different situations.

Comment: @bananashakealchemist: Your first comment doesn't really make sense. You are asking for a *"simpler"* solution, that doesn't make use of pre-built, tested API calls. Those are orthogonal requirements. You need to pick one. If you really want to traverse the PE structure, be prepared to deal with images that violate the documented standard. Appropriate error handling is likely what makes calling the Windows API a lot easier than rolling your own.

Comment: Can we extract  file version for exe/dll which is not loaded? If not is there any other way?

Comment: @Mayur if the file is not loaded yet, then just use `GetFileVersionInfo()` + `VerQueryValue()` normally. That is the easiest way. Otherwise, you have to load the DLL/EXE into memory yourself and parse its PE header manually.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thats great input. I tried it and worked. Thank you.